# python - "merge based on a partial match" - Improving performance of function

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have the below script - which aims to create a "merge based on a partial match" functionality since this is not possible with the normal `.merge()` funct to the best of my knowledge.

The below works / returns the desired result, but unfortunately, it's incredibly slow to the point that it's almost unusable where I need it.

Been looking around at other Stack Overflow posts that contain similar problems, but haven't yet been able to find a faster solution.

Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished would be appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame([  'https://wwww.example.com/hi', 'https://wwww.example.com/tri', 'https://wwww.example.com/bi', 'https://wwww.example.com/hihibi' ]
    ,columns = ['pages']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['hi','bi','geo']
    ,columns = ['ngrams']
)

def join_on_partial_match(full_values=None, matching_criteria=None):
    # Changing columns name with index number
    full_values.columns.values[0] = "full"
    matching_criteria.columns.values[0] = "ngram_match"

    # Creating matching column so all rows match on join
    full_values['join'] = 1
    matching_criteria['join'] = 1
    dfFull = full_values.merge(matching_criteria, on='join').drop('join', axis=1)

    # Dropping the 'join' column we created to join the 2 tables
    matching_criteria = matching_criteria.drop('join', axis=1)

    # identifying matching and returning bool values based on whether match exists
    dfFull['match'] = dfFull.apply(lambda x: x.full.find(x.ngram_match), axis=1).ge(0)

    # filtering dataset to only 'True' rows
    final = dfFull[dfFull['match'] == True] 

    final = final.drop('match', axis=1)
    
    return final 

join = join_on_partial_match(full_values=df1,matching_criteria=df2)
print(join)
```

```
>>                 full ngram_match
0       https://wwww.example.com/hi          hi
7       https://wwww.example.com/bi          bi
9   https://wwww.example.com/hihibi          hi
10  https://wwww.example.com/hihibi          bi
```

Comment: I propose switch to numpy, do the work there, then return to pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested - ended up figuring out 2 ways to do this.

1. First returns all matches (i.e., it duplicates the input value and matches with all partial matches)
2. Only returns the first match.
   Both are extremely fast. Just ended up using a pretty simple masking script

```
def partial_match_join_all_matches_returned(full_values=None, matching_criteria=None):
    """The partial_match_join_first_match_returned() function takes two series objects and returns a dataframe with all matching values (duplicating the full value).
    Args:
        full_values = None: This is the series that contains the full values for matching pair.
        partial_values = None: This is the series that contains the partial values for matching pair.
    Returns:
            A dataframe with 2 columns - 'full' and 'match'.  
    """
    start_join1 = time.time()
    
    matching_criteria = matching_criteria.to_frame("match")
    full_values = full_values.to_frame("full")
    full_values = full_values.drop_duplicates() 
    
    output=[]

    for n in matching_criteria['match']:
        mask = full_values['full'].str.contains(n, case=False, na=False)
        df = full_values[mask]
        df_copy = df.copy()
        df_copy['match'] = n 
        # df = df.loc[n, 'match'] 
        output.append(df_copy)

    final = pd.concat(output)

    end_join1 = (time.time() - start_join1)
    end_join1 = str(round(end_join1, 2))
    len_join1 = len(final)
    
    return final
```

```
def partial_match_join_first_match_returned(full_values=None, matching_criteria=None):
    """The partial_match_join_first_match_returned() function takes two series objects and returns a dataframe with the first matching value.
    Args:
        full_values = None: This is the series that contains the full values for matching pair.
        partial_values = None: This is the series that contains the partial values for matching pair.
    Returns:
            A dataframe with 2 columns - 'full' and 'match'.  
    """
    start_singlejoin = time.time()

    matching_criteria = matching_criteria.to_frame("match")
    full_values = full_values.to_frame("full").drop_duplicates() 
    output=[]
    for n in matching_criteria['match']:
        mask = full_values['full'].str.contains(n, case=False, na=False)
        df = full_values[mask]
        df_copy = df.copy()
        df_copy['match'] = n 
        # leaves us with only the 1st of each URL
        df_copy.drop_duplicates(subset=['full'])
        output.append(df_copy)

    final = pd.concat(output)

    end_singlejoin = (time.time() - start_singlejoin)
    end_singlejoin = str(round(end_singlejoin, 2))
    len_singlejoin = len(final)

    return final
```